# How to display 'c' array values alone from the given JSON document below using MongoDB?

Tags: json, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

I am a newbie to MongoDB. I am experimenting the various ways of extracting fields from a document inside collection.
Here in the below JSON document, I am finding it difficult to get extract it according to my need

```
{  
   "_id":1,
   "dependencies":{  
      "a":[  
         "hello",
         "hi"
      ],
      "b":[  
         "Hmmm"
      ],
      "c":[  
         "Vanilla",
         "Strawberry",
         "Pista"
        ],
      "d":[  
         "Carrot",
         "Cauliflower",
         "Potato",
         "Cabbage"
      ]
   },
   "productid":"25",
   "date":"Thu Jul 30 11:36:49 PDT 2015"
}
```

I need to display the following output:

```
c:[  
         "Vanilla",
         "Strawberry",
         "Pista"
    ]
```

Can anyone please help me in solving it?

Answer (score 1):

[MongoDB Aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) comes into rescue to get the result you are looking for :

[$Project](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)--> Passes along the documents with only the specified fields to the next stage in the pipeline. The specified fields can be existing fields from the input documents or newly computed fields.

```
db.collection.aggregate( [
                   { $project : 
                      { c: "$dependencies.c", _id : 0 } 
                   }
              ]).pretty();
```

As per the output you required, we just need to project ( display) the field "dependencies.c" , so we are creating a new field "c" and assigining the value of the "dependencies.c" into it.

Also by defalut "_id" field will be display along with the result, since you dont need it, so we are suppressing of the _id field by assigining "_id" : <0 or false>, so that it will not display the _id field in the output.

The above query will fetch you the result as below :

```
     "c" : [ 
             "Vanilla",
             "Strawberry", 
             "Pista" 
           ]
```

Comment: Thank you Yathish. A effecient solution I believe. Will look into the basics fully as I have to get it right